# Compare text files skipping N symbols from each line

Tags: text-processing, file-comparison

Can I compare two text files skipping N symbols from start of the each line?

For example **file1**:

```
2018-05-31 12:00:00 This is the first line of text.
2018-05-31 12:00:00 This is the second line of text.
2018-05-31 12:00:00 This is the third line of text.
2018-05-31 12:00:00 This is the forth line of text.
2018-05-31 12:00:00 This is the fifth line of text.
```

and **file2**:

```
2018-05-31 12:00:01 This is the first line of text.
2018-05-31 12:00:02 This is the second line of text.
2018-05-31 12:00:03 This is the third line of text.
2018-05-31 12:00:04 This is the forth line of text.
2018-05-31 12:00:05 This is the fifth line of text.
```

If I compare two files line by line - they are different because of the seconds in time stamp.

But if I skip first 19 symbols from the start of each line in both files (date and time) - these files are identical. How to do that using shell command (script)?

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `cut`:

```
diff <(cut -c 20- file1) <(cut -c 20- file2)
```

Note: with GNU `cut` the `-c` character option actually works on bytes not characters, but this should be fine as long as your output starts with date/time stamps and not special characters.

Comment: If cut may be an issue, then use sed: `sed 's/^.\{1,20\}//' file`.

Comment: Thank you very much, @Jesse_b - your solution works exactly the way I need!

Comment: When I use this to diff the files in two directories, the names of the files are omitted in the output (if I just do `diff dir1 dir2` the names are included). Why? Can this be fixed?